# Authenticate user for secure spring service with CAS RESTful API ticket

Tags: cas

I have successfuly setup CAS server. I want to authenticate user for secure service (in spring application), so used RESTful API to get the tickets for user. I am able to get tickets by two step call to cas/v1/tickets and cas/v1/tickets/{TGT} for secure service, but when I tried to call that service using the generated ticket like

localhost:8080/secure1?ticket?ST-ttyyy..." it returns a response content of cas login page.

I think, I am missing some point in my configuration either

"services.xml" of my spring application or in cas configuration.

Spring app settings.xml

```
<bean id="pgtStorage"     class="org.jasig.cas.client.proxy.ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl"/>

    <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
        <property name="service" value="http://localhost:8080/EFormRestServer/business/user/10000007" />
        <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
        <property name="artifactParameter" value="ticket"/>
    </bean>
 <security:http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint">        
            <security:anonymous enabled="true" />
            <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casFilter" />
        </security:http> 

        <bean id="casFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" ref="pgtStorage"/>
    <property name="proxyReceptorUrl" value="/business/test"/>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"/>
    <property name="authenticationDetailsSource">
      <bean class=
        "org.springframework.security.cas.web.authentication.ServiceAuthenticationDetailsSource"/>
    </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="casEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginUrl"
            value="http://localhost:8080/cas/login" />
            <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
    </bean>
 <!-- To delegate authorization to method calls rather than to urls -->
 <!-- (Thus, we don't need to set any url-interceptor in this conf) -->
 <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
    <bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.eform.rest.service.RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <bean id="myFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean> 


    <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
        <property name="ticketValidator">
      <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyTicketValidator">
        <constructor-arg value="https://localhost:8443/cas"/>
        <property name="proxyCallbackUrl"
            value="localhost:8080/EFormRestServer/business"/>
        <property name="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" ref="pgtStorage"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="statelessTicketCache">
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.EhCacheBasedTicketCache">
        <property name="cache">
          <bean class="net.sf.ehcache.Cache"
              init-method="initialise" destroy-method="dispose">
            <constructor-arg value="casTickets"/>
            <constructor-arg value="50"/>
            <constructor-arg value="true"/>
            <constructor-arg value="false"/>
            <constructor-arg value="3600"/>
            <constructor-arg value="900"/>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
        <property name="key" value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <security:jdbc-user-service id="userService"
        data-source-ref="dataSource"
        users-by-username-query="select user_name, password, true from user where user_name = ?"
        authorities-by-username-query="select u.user_name, r.role from user u,user_role r where u.role_id=r.role and user_name = ?" />
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After comparing with my study [demo](https://github.com/btpka3/btpka3.github.com/blob/master/java/spring/first-sso/first-spring-stateless/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml), I think you missing the following configuration :

```
<bean id="serviceProperties"
      class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
  ...
  <property name="authenticateAllArtifacts"       value="true"/>
</bean>
```

See Spring Security Reference Documentation [22.3.4 Proxy Ticket Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#cas-pt).

Comment: I'm trying to use your example for RESTful CAS but continuously getting 401 response code on https://localhost:8443/first-spring-cas/testProxy.do url - [http-nio-8443-exec-8] [first-spring-stateless] DEBUG o.s.s.c.web.CasAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: 
            The supplied proxy callback url 'https://localhost:8443/first-spring-stateless/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor' could not be authenticated.   What can be a reason of that ?

Comment: I have created a separate question for this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256197/stateless-cas-the-supplied-proxy-callback-url-j-spring-cas-security-proxyrecep  Could you please take a look at this ?