# Stateless CAS - The supplied proxy callback url j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor' could not be authenticated

Tags: spring, cas, jasig

I need to secure my RESTful stateless webservices with CAS and right now I'm trying to follow this [Spring Stateless CAS](https://github.com/btpka3/btpka3.github.com/tree/master/java/spring/first-sso/first-spring-stateless) demo but continuously getting a following error:

```
22:42:27.885 [http-nio-8443-exec-8] [first-spring-stateless] DEBUG o.s.s.c.web.CasAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: 
            The supplied proxy callback url 'https://localhost:8443/first-spring-stateless/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor' could not be authenticated.
```

when accessing `https://localhost:8443/first-spring-cas/testProxy.do` url

This is for example my `appointmentServiceUrl` - https://localhost:8443/first-spring-stateless/appointment.jsp?ticket=PT-110-a2a6eOE3lwImcwGpZ2Jp-cas.example.com

[image]

What can be a reason of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding

```
<property name="proxyReceptorUrl"               value="/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor"/>
```

to `casFilter`

This is `casFilter` in the `applicationContext-security.xml`:

```
 <bean id="casFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager"          ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="proxyGrantingTicketStorage"     ref="pgtStorage"/>
    <property name="serviceProperties"              ref="serviceProperties"/>

    <property name="proxyReceptorUrl"               value="/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor"/>
    <property name="authenticationDetailsSource">
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.authentication.ServiceAuthenticationDetailsSource"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Comment: Can you please tell what exactly `casFilter` is here ?

Comment: @AnujKu I have updated my answer with the casFilter declaration. Honestly, I do not remember much details on this subject because it was a few years ago. Anyway, hope, it will help you.

Comment: @ alexanoid Thank you for the quick update. Just a quick question, if you remember `j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor` endpoint is something spring gives you by default ?

Comment: I may be wrong but AFAIK this is something you should get with Spring CAS Security insode of your application connected with CAS. For example you can find the mention of `/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor` configuration for version 3.1.x for `proxyCallbackUrl` - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/cas.html. For the current version the url is slightly different https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cas.html - `<property name="proxyCallbackUrl"
  value="https://localhost:8443/cas-sample/login/cas/proxyreceptor"/>`